# Kibana is very slow to load result

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have tried Elasticsearch 2.3.2 and Kibana Version 4.5.0 to store big Json object containing a lot of info of Windows OS, an example of json type is the followed:

```
{
  "_index": "siem",
  "_type": "rmd-siem",
  "_id": "2b1fc911-85f6-48f3-a7ba-b9e5f6e8b38f",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "timestamp": "2016-05-08T15:00:37.000Z",
    "BIOS": {
      "CURRENTLANGUAGE": "en|US|iso8859-1",
      "BIOSCHARACTERISTICS": "{4;7;9;11;12;15;16;19;21;22;23;24;27;28;30;32;33;40;41;42;48;56;57;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79}",
      "NAME": "xxxxx",
      "SERIALNUMBER": "xxxxx",
      "DESCRIPTION": "xxxcv",
      "SMBIOSMINORVERSION": 6,
      "INSTALLABLELANGUAGES": 1,
      "RELEASEDATE": "24-May-2010 12:00:00 AM",
      "STATUS": "OK",
      "LISTOFLANGUAGES": "{en|US|iso8859-1}",
      "HOST": "GOLFINHO_OSM1",
      "SMBIOSPRESENT": "TRUE",
      "PRIMARYBIOS": "TRUE",
      "VERSION": "DELL   - 1",
      "TARGETOPERATINGSYSTEM": 0,
      "SMBIOSBIOSVERSION": "1.3.6",
      "SOFTWAREELEMENTID": "xxxccv",
      "SMBIOSMAJORVERSION": 2,
      "SOFTWAREELEMENTSTATE": 3,
      "TIMESTAMP": "2016-05-08 15:00:37",
      "MANUFACTURER": "Dell Inc."
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "timestamp": [
      1462719637000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1462719637000
  ]
}
```

I have other big json that they are json array containing json object with many data. So I have few object but with very info.
While I tryed Kibana to show the info I saw that the load data for a few hits (results) is very slow in loading phase.
I think that the issue could be to amount of data (a lot info inside json object) because from the test performed I have seen about 22 seconds to receive data and to render the data inside Kibana others 40 seconds for total of 277 hits.

[image]
I ask you if the issue is the big json or there is another reason. Thanks